# Same reducer but different state

Tags: angular, ngrx

Is it possible to use same reducers with different states? Right now my both modules uses same state, so it shares data between modules, but i need them to be separated.

page-1.module.ts

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    PageComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    StoreModule.forFeature('page-1', PageReducer) // I wanna use same reducer but different state
  ]
})
```

page-2.module.ts

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    PageComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    StoreModule.forFeature('page-2', PageReducer) // I wanna use same reducer but different state
  ]
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes this does work. Each reducer instance has its own state.